# asp.net A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using ASP.Net C# with SQL Server 2012

My C# Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class autorefresh_create_emi : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["paconn"].ToString());
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("select max(f_casenum) from c_detail", con);
        string check_max = com1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        if (check_max == "0")
        {
        }
        else
        {
            string st_id = "";
            Int64 st = 0;
            string max_id = "";
            Int64 en = 0;

            SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("select top 1(f_casenum) from c_emi where f_casenum not in (select top 1 (f_casenum) from c_detail order by f_casenum) order by f_casenum", con);
            com2.CommandTimeout = 0;
            st_id = com2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            st_id = st_id.Substring(2);
            st = Convert.ToInt64(st_id);

            max_id = check_max;
            max_id = max_id.Substring(2);
            en = Convert.ToInt64(max_id);

            for (Int64 i = st; i <= en; i++)
            {
                string f_casenum = "PA" + i;
                string c_status = "";
                string f_tenure = "";

                SqlCommand com3 = new SqlCommand("select * from c_detail where f_casenum=@f_casenum", con);
                com3.CommandTimeout = 0;
                com3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_casenum", f_casenum);

                SqlDataReader reader3 = com3.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader3.Read())
                {
                    f_tenure = reader3["f_tenure"].ToString().Trim();
                    c_status = reader3["c_status"].ToString();
                }
                reader3.Close();

                if (c_status == "Full Paid")
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    string row_check = "";
                    SqlCommand com4 = new SqlCommand("select count(f_invoice) from c_emi where f_casenum=@f_casenum", con);
                    com4.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_casenum", f_casenum);
                    row_check = com4.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Trim();

                    if (f_tenure.Equals(row_check))
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string st_id_invoice = "";
                        Int64 st_invoice = 0;
                        string max_id_invoice = "";
                        Int64 en_invoice = 0;

                        SqlCommand com5 = new SqlCommand("select min(f_invoice) from c_emi where f_casenum=@f_casenum", con);
                        com5.CommandTimeout = 0;
                        com5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_casenum", f_casenum);
                        st_id_invoice = com5.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                        st_id_invoice = st_id_invoice.Substring(3);
                        st_invoice = Convert.ToInt64(st_id_invoice);

                        SqlCommand com6 = new SqlCommand("select max(f_invoice) from c_emi where f_casenum=@f_casenum", con);
                        com6.CommandTimeout = 0;
                        com6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_casenum", f_casenum);
                        max_id_invoice = com6.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                        max_id_invoice = max_id_invoice.Substring(3);
                        en_invoice = Convert.ToInt64(max_id_invoice);

                        for (Int64 j = st_invoice; j <= en_invoice; j++)
                        {
                            string invoice_date = "";
                            string f_emi_due = "";
                            string f_total_emi = "";
                            string f_emi = "";
                            string f_b_curr = "";

                            string f_invoice = "PAI" + j;
                            string f_casenum1 = "";

                            SqlCommand com7 = new SqlCommand("select * from c_emi where f_invoice=@f_invoice", con);
                            com7.CommandTimeout = 0;
                            com7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_invoice", f_invoice);

                            SqlDataReader reader7 = com7.ExecuteReader();
                            if (reader7.Read())
                            {
                                f_casenum1 = reader7["f_casenum"].ToString();
                                f_emi = reader7["f_emi"].ToString();
                                f_emi_due = reader7["f_emi_due"].ToString();
                                f_total_emi = reader7["f_total_emi"].ToString();
                                f_b_curr = reader7["f_b_curr"].ToString();
                                invoice_date = reader7["invoice_date"].ToString();
                            }
                            reader7.Close();

                            if (f_casenum == f_casenum1)
                            {
                                DateTime currr = DateTime.Now;
                                DateTime INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currr, "India Standard Time");

                                DateTime curr = INDIAN_ZONE;
                                string curr_invoicedate = curr.ToShortDateString();
                                DateTime check_invoicedate = Convert.ToDateTime(invoice_date);
                                check_invoicedate = check_invoicedate.AddDays(30);
                                check_invoicedate = Convert.ToDateTime(check_invoicedate);
                                string exit_date = check_invoicedate.ToShortDateString();

                                string f_emi_duedate = check_invoicedate.AddDays(10).ToShortDateString();
                                string invoice_date1 = check_invoicedate.ToShortDateString();

                                SqlCommand com8 = new SqlCommand("select f_casenum from c_emi where f_casenum=@f_casenum and CONVERT(date,invoice_date,101)=@invoice_date", con);
                                com8.CommandTimeout = 0;
                                com8.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_casenum", f_casenum);
                                com8.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoice_date", exit_date);

                                string check_exitdate = "";

                                SqlDataReader reader8 = com8.ExecuteReader();
                                if (reader8.Read())
                                {
                                    check_exitdate = reader8["f_casenum"].ToString();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                }

                                if (check_exitdate != "")
                                {
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (curr >= check_invoicedate)
                                    {
                                        string value = "0";
                                        string owner = "";
                                        string i_status = "Unlock";

                                        SqlCommand com9 = new SqlCommand("select MAX(f_invoice) from c_emi", con);
                                        com9.CommandTimeout = 0;
                                        string maxid1 = com9.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                                        string id1 = maxid1;
                                        Int64 code = 100000000001;
                                        string c = "PAI";

                                        if (id1.Substring(0, 1) != "P")
                                        {
                                            id1 = code.ToString();
                                            id1 = c + id1.ToString();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            id1 = id1.Substring(3);
                                            Int64 a = Convert.ToInt64(id1);
                                            a = a + 1;
                                            id1 = c + a.ToString();
                                        }
                                        id1 = id1.ToString();

                                        SqlCommand com11 = new SqlCommand("insert into c_emi values(@f_casenum,@f_b_amt,@f_emi,@f_emi_duedate,@f_invoice,@invoice_date,@f_overdue_amt,@f_emi_paid,@f_emi_due,@f_total_emi,@f_b_curr,@i_status,@owner,@convi_charges,@paidemi_date)", con);
                                        com11.CommandTimeout = 0;

                                        SqlParameter obj1 = new SqlParameter("@f_casenum", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj1.Value = f_casenum;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj1);

                                        SqlParameter obj2 = new SqlParameter("@f_overdue_amt", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj2.Value = value;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj2);

                                        SqlParameter obj3 = new SqlParameter("@f_emi_paid", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj3.Value = value;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj3);

                                        SqlParameter obj4 = new SqlParameter("@f_emi_due", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj4.Value = value;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj4);

                                        SqlParameter obj5 = new SqlParameter("@f_total_emi", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj5.Value = f_emi;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj5);

                                        SqlParameter obj6 = new SqlParameter("@f_emi", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj6.Value = f_emi;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj6);

                                        SqlParameter obj7 = new SqlParameter("@f_emi_duedate", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj7.Value = f_emi_duedate;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj7);

                                        SqlParameter obj8 = new SqlParameter("@f_invoice", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj8.Value = id1;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj8);

                                        SqlParameter obj9 = new SqlParameter("@invoice_date", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj9.Value = invoice_date1;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj9);

                                        SqlParameter obj10 = new SqlParameter("@f_b_amt", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj10.Value = f_b_curr;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj10);

                                        SqlParameter obj11 = new SqlParameter("@f_b_curr", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj11.Value = f_b_curr;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj11);

                                        SqlParameter obj12 = new SqlParameter("@i_status", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj12.Value = i_status;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj12);

                                        SqlParameter obj13 = new SqlParameter("@owner", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj13.Value = owner;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj13);

                                        SqlParameter obj14 = new SqlParameter("@convi_charges", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj14.Value = value;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj14);

                                        SqlParameter obj15 = new SqlParameter("@paidemi_date", DbType.StringFixedLength);
                                        obj15.Value = owner;
                                        com11.Parameters.Add(obj15);

                                        com11.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I have large database and my query is inserted many number of record on table when i run the web page

I recieve the following Error :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has
>   occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session
>   Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)

on the following Code

```
Line 111:                            com7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_invoice", f_invoice);
Line 112:
Line 113:                            SqlDataReader reader7 = com7.ExecuteReader();
Line 114:                            if (reader7.Read())
Line 115:                            {
```

My ErrorLog file says :

> 2015-01-13 11:27:23.96 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State:
>   8.
>
> 2015-01-13 11:27:23.96 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'.
>   Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT:
>   108.171.243.19]

So what's the issue..??

Comment: Check if you are closing reader and you may be having too many connections

Comment: it seems your network connection is down and not able to reach database please verify that part first and second verify you are providing correnct user name and passowrd

Comment: @Adil yes i close the reader using reader.Close();

Comment: are you sure the reader is closed if an exception occurs (i.e. it is closed within a finally block)

Comment: @PranayRana yes i provided the correct username and password.

Comment: when i run this web page it inserted some rows on table but not all.

Comment: ok i update my question with my c# code please wait.

Comment: please check my updated c# code

Comment: @Adil please see my updated c# code.